# Skip rendering of HTML using Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

Is there a way to force Jekyll to bypass the rendering of HTML files? I am attempting to build exclusively files of different extensions instead of the default '.html' while defining the content in markdown files.

Currently, this is being achieved by using a generator plugin to build those files. Ideally, I would be able to specify alternative file types in the configuration and bypass the rendering of HTML.

Is this possible without resorting to post-generation file cleanup?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by omitting front-matter.

If you omit front-matter from your files then Jekyll will not process them and will output them as-is. However, you then can't use Markdown for content because Jekyll doesn't process the files other than to copy them to _site.